# Is it Possible to use Mouse Movement in a Shortcut?

Tags: x11, keyboard-shortcuts, mouse, input, mouse-gestures

I'm interested in creating shortcut keys that use mouse movement as part of their trigger to send a keycode, for example so that I could have a shortcut like:

```
ctrl + alt + [mouse movement down]
```

Could be the equivalent of page down, while moving up might page up instead.

I imagine this would be subject to the normal key repeating settings and would probably need a threshold set as to how much movement in a particular direction is required to trigger the shortcut, but with how easy it is to capture MotionNotify events using xev, and that it states the new mouse position it seems like it would be reasonably easy to determine direction.

Comment: I think reacting to Ctrl+Alt+mouse-move-down would be classified as a mouse gesture.